# Export sql server table into xml

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

Hello I want to export `SQL Server 2005` table into `XML` using programatically.

there is any way in `SQL server 2005` through that can export table into `XML`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx